# How to avoid "RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory." during inference of one single image?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I am facing the famous "CUDA out of memory" error.

```
File "DATA\instance-mask-r-cnn-torch\venv\lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\detection\roi_heads.py", line 416, in paste_mask_in_image
    im_mask = torch.zeros((im_h, im_w), dtype=mask.dtype, device=mask.device)
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 24.00 MiB (GPU 0; 2.00 GiB total capacity; 1.66 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 1.73 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

[image: Windows task manager]

Windows 10, CUDA 11.3, torch 0.11.0+cu113, torchvision 0.12.0+cu113

On the ENV I played with `PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=max_split_size_mb:32`, 128, 8, 24, 32... without success.

An image of size 640x512 (1.5mb) works, another one of size 3264x1840 (1.75mb) leads to an OOME.

```
import torchvision.transforms
from torchvision.models.detection import mask_rcnn
import torch
from PIL import Image
import gc

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    print(f'GPU: {torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)}')
    device = torch.device('cuda')
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
else:
    device = torch.device('cpu')

print(f'Device: {device}')

model = mask_rcnn.maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)
print(model.eval())

model.to(device)

img_path = 'images/tv_image05.png'
img_path = 'images/DJI_20220519110029_0001_W.JPG'
img_path = 'images/DJI_20220519110143_0021_T.JPG'
img_path = 'images/WP_20160104_09_52_53_Pro.jpg'

img = Image.open(img_path).convert("RGB")

img_tensor = torchvision.transforms.functional.to_tensor(img)

with torch.no_grad():
    predictions = model([img_tensor.cuda()])

print(predictions)

gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

So far i found lots of hints, reducing batch size. But I am not using training mode. what else can I do to be able to process images of sizes up to 7mb?

Comment: You are showing the stats of GPU 2 while the error happened on GPU 0. And BTW 24 MB is about the uncompressed size of a 3264x1840x32bit image.

Comment: Well, thats a point. The script outputs the following for GPU:0:
GPU: Quadro M1000M, Device: cuda.
And because the amplitude of the diagram correlates with the execution of the script, i simply trust that the model runs on the CUDA GPU. For the Intel GPU I did not install any special software for CUDA. Would this be possible?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3264x1840 image is going to be 72MB in float32. Since it works for your 640x512 image, I'd suggest resizing it.
Simply add `torchvision.transforms.functional.resize(img,512)`

Another common trick is to quantize the model and the image to float16 but this may degrade the model accuracy depending on what you're doing.

Comment: Yes, this time the larger images processed as well. Is there a way to "estimate" the memory demand of a model in action? Or is it that 2GB is considered not useful when it comes to instance segmentation of bigger images, biger than 640x512 e.g.?

Comment: It's possible to calculate the sizes by going through the code and seeing what the input and output sizes are at each layer but it's easier to do so experimentally. You should also keep in mind that whatever network you're using may not be trained on such large images to begin with.

Comment: I thought about dividing the large images into smaller ones, but then I would need to overlap the smaller images to be able to detect objects which are located at the boundaries. And for this reason I have worries with this approach.